# Why doesn't twitter:image work properly when posting link in Twitter?

Tags: twitter, meta-tags, twitter-card

This is the current twitter card data I have inside `<head>`

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@tradukka">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Currency exchange: United States Dollar (USD) - Argentine Peso (ARS)">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Currencies exchange updated in real time: United States Dollar (USD) - Argentine Peso (ARS) / 1 USD...">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://tradukka.com/meta/359ac65be829e896c12a3126fa9c71d0.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:image:width" content="750">
<meta name="twitter:image:height" content="370">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://tradukka.com/currency/usd/ars">
```

If I send a tweet with that link, all the information is being shown in the tweet, except the image:

[image]

I also tried using the [card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator):

[image]

...it fetches everything except the image.

Also, I already tried using **twitter:image:src** as well. The domain is whitelisted. Any ideas on why the image is not being displayed inside the tweet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by `robots.txt`. Make sure that the twitter bot is allowed to crawl the directory containing the twitter images (in this case, /meta).

Comment: i am also facing the same issue ,  please refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/50529190/1338683?stw=2. after the block we have allowed the robot allow to images folder , still have issue

Comment: Our sitemap was missing the page in question. Once added, the image showed up as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem.
The solution is just switching from `summary card with large image` to `summary`.
To apply this you have to edit the script

```
"meta content='summary_large_image' name='twitter:card'"
```

as

```
"meta content='summary' name='twitter:card'"
```

This solves the problem, but I don't know why the large image type cards are not working.

Comment: Hi! Actually my issue was solved simply by removing the robots.txt restriction. Both the summary and summary_large_image should work ok.

Comment: i think i have to test this one also . how much time it would take the search engine take to recrawl. or it will access when we access the site