# The twitter image is not displaying, robot.txt allowed access to images folder

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

Hi twitter card is not showing up the image , when tested in twitter card validator i got an warning message like this "specified by the 'twitter:image' metatag may be restricted by the site's robots.txt file, which will prevent Twitter from fetching it."  The image is 600X300 and is accessibly through browser.

I have specified the following meta tags
twitter:card
twitter:site
twitter:creator
twitter:title
twitter:url
twitter:imag

Comment: Do you have a robots.txt on your site?

Comment: yes Terence, do the twitter summary card have any resolution constrains

Comment: Does your robots.txt allow the Twitter crawler? Look at this page for details https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started

Comment: thanks  terence, it worked ;) . thanks